# Feature Importance Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, feature-selection

My dataset has around 1000 features and 30k rows.

All the feautres have value either 1 or 0. My target variable is **Size** which 3 classes : Small, Medium and Large. I have around 5k "small" data points, 9k "Medium" data points and 20K "Large" data points. I want to find feature importance. I am not sure which algorithm will work best for features with only 1s and 0s. I tried Chi2 but accuracy is very low:

```
#find best scored 10 features
select_feature = SelectKBest(chi2, k=10).fit(X_train, Y_train)

X_train_2 = select_feature.transform(X_train)
X_test_2 = select_feature.transform(X_test)

clf_rf_2 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=-1, random_state = 100)      
clr_rf_2 = clf_rf_2.fit(X_train_2,Y_train)
ac_2 = accuracy_score(Y_test,clf_rf_2.predict(X_test_2))
print('Accuracy is: ',ac_2)
cm_2 = confusion_matrix(Y_test,clf_rf_2.predict(X_test_2))
```

My accuracy is only 58% and the model is only good in predicting "Large" data points. Below is the Confusion Matrix

```
      Small   Medium   Large
Small  6      17       3000
Medium 9      9        2000 
Large  31     32       7500
```

I mostly have 2 questions:

1. I am not sure which algorithm will work for best features with only 1s and 0s
2. How do I get higher accuracy using chi2 (predict Small and Medium class better)

Thanks! I would really appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Would the result be better if you use larger `k`?

Comment: I have tried k = 100 but the accuracy didn't improve much

Comment: how about `lightgbm`?